# Is Laravel Terminable Middleware still run on Exception?

Tags: laravel

For exceptions that are handled by Laravel's exception handler, is [Terminable Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#terminable-middleware) still executed when such an exception occurs?

For that matter, are "After" Middleware executed when an exception occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's look in framework code. In `Kernel` class we have a `handle()` method:

```
    public function handle($request)
    {
        try {
            $request->enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();

            $response = $this->sendRequestThroughRouter($request);
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            $this->reportException($e);

            $response = $this->renderException($request, $e);
        }

        $this->app['events']->dispatch(
            new RequestHandled($request, $response)
        );

        return $response;
    }
```

As we can see, all exceptions will be catched and transforms to returned response. In `index.php` we can see how this response comes to `terminate()` method:

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

In total - answer is **Yes, terminate chain will be executed if exception occurs.**